# Function of '+' in #if defined?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MIN 0

#if defined(MIN) + defined(MAX)

#define MAX 10

#endif

int main()

{

    printf("%d %d\n", MAX, MIN);

    return 0;

}
```

**Output**
`10 0`
What is the meaning of `#if defined(MIN) + defined(MAX)`?
Why it is working when `#define MAX 10` is defined later?

Comment: Where did you find such a thing?

Comment: That's not very precise, "the Internet" is not a reference. If you put something here (or publically elsewhere) always give a valid reference. I really would be interested in which context such crufty code occurs.

Comment: @JensGustedt ... crufty, interesting use of adjective! I agree, a reference would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The `defined` operator](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Defined.html) evaluates to 0 or 1 depending on whether the symbol is defined.

Arithmetic works in preprocessor expressions, and 1 + 0 is 1 so the `#if` is taken.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, it is the same as `||`:

```
#if defined(MIN) || defined(MAX)
    ...
#endif
```

The `defined(...)` operator produces a `0` or `1` integer, and `#if` takes any integer expression, as long as it can be evaluated at the time of preprocessing.

Using `+` in preprocessor conditions lets you build more interesting constructs, for example

```
#if (defined(MIN) + defined(MAX) + defined(AVG)) >= 2
    ...
#endif
```

This means "at least two of the three items, `{MIN, MAX, AVG}` are defined".

Answer (score 3):

You are allowed to do simple math in the preprocessor. `#if defined(...)` evaluates to an integer zero or one. `defined(MIN)` is `1`, while `defined(MAX)` is `0`, so the whole expression evaluates to `1 = true`, and `MAX` gets defined.